# AWS Cognito UserPool : why Cognito creates duplicate email records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

In my User Pool I have currently 2 options

1. SignUp using Email and Password
2. SignUp using Google (Federated)

Steps:

1. SignUp user with Email and Password
2. LogOut and then SignUp using Google (Federated)

Result: on the first step, user is created in Cognito, but after Google SignUp it is also create 2nd record with the same Email.

Why? And how to resolve?

Thanks in advance ...!

I have tried with the Lambda function but it's not working

Comment: Identity is a combination of provider ID plus user ID (typically email address), not just the latter.

Comment: Cognito tracks those separately. It shouldn't be a problem as long as you use the email address as the account identifier in your underlying application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark B, can you please help me understand how i can configure email address as the account identifier on AWS cognitor. Can point to me some article or any reference. Thanks.